# Securing traffic sent over HTTP, Client side

Tags: http, https

I am currently writing up on HTTP and HTTPS and the advantages of HTTPS. I was thinking, is it possible to securely send data to a server i.e login, which is just HTTP. The result I was thinking that the login credentials are encrypted before being sent e.g. aren't readable (using wireshark) but the server can still retrieve the information.

I can understand why this wouldn't be possible, how to make the server the only one to read the credentials.

Again this was just a thought.

Comment: Right now this is not a question and also completely off-topic here on Super User. However, it might fit on [security.se] after some rewording to turn it into a proper question.

Comment: Sorry about that. Only really use Stackoverflow of the Stack exchange sites. I do think though it is a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually possible. You could implement the cryptographic algorithms SSL uses in client-side JavaScript and encrypt your date with a public key. Only the application on your server would have the corresponding private key and thus nobody could read the data even when using plain HTTP.

However, there is one big disadvantage compared to SSL: You are not protected from Man-in-the-Middle attacks (who would replace the public key with one where he has the private key). Doing the same with HTTPS would require a corrupt/malicious CA or the user accepting an invalid/self-signed certificate.